# Regex, how to recognise 2 or 3 words (of any non space) delimited by spaces

Tags: java, regex

I am using java and am trying to write a regex that excepts this:

```
jkdsl;a asdfasdf asdfjkl;
```

and this

```
789u 13789u
```

but not this

```
HJKs9
```

or this

```
hiop hiopwer rewk3 fheio2
```

So far I have this, but it doesn't seem to work (I have used an online regex tester):

```
(\S+\s){2,3}
```

I think:

- \S+ means more than one non space
- \s means a whitespace
- (X){2,3} means 2-3 (inclusive) consecutive occurrences of X

Where have I gone wrong?

(I have put it in java as `"(\\S+\\s){2,3}"` as \ is an escape)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the lines which has two or three words.

```
^\S+(?:\s+\S+){1,2}$
```

Java regex would be,

```
^\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){1,2}$
```

`\S+` matches one or more non-space characters. `\s+` matches one or more space characters. `{1,2}` called repetition quantifier which repeats the previous token that is `(?:\s+\S+)` one or two times. `$` Asserts that we are at the end of the line.

OR

Use this if your input contains preceding or following spaces.

```
"^\\s*\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){1,2}\\s*$"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gQ3kS4/39)

Comment: Use this `^ *\S+(?:\s+\S+){1,2} *$` if the string is precede and followed by spaces.

Comment: What does the '?:' mean? (I understand the rest) [I have already trimmed the strings anyway]

Comment: `(?:..)` called non-capturing group. It will do the matching operation only.

Comment: @rchang yes, but `\\s` matches newline chars also.

Comment: From what I understand, it should work without it (it does appear to)? (the '?:')

Comment: It is better to have this `(?:...)`. It is probably faster, if only by a little bit, since there’s no way to use capture groups in the regular expression without having them returned in the results.